# Onkeydown event firing in IE and Chrome but not FireFox

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, events, keyboard

Why does my keyboard interactivity code function properly in IE and Chrome, but not FireFox? The full code is at http://sgdk2.enigmadream.com/ben/Html5Sample.html.  Feel free to download and edit the file locally to test corrections (please do in the interest of skipping over wrong answers to the right answer :) ). It's entirely self-contained 100% in the one HTML file.

For your convenience, here, I believe, is all the code involved:

```
var keyboardState;
keyboardState = new Object();
keyboardState.key= { None:0, Enter:13, Shift:16,
/* etc... */};

keyboardState.keyState = new Array();
keyboardState.handleKeyDown = function(e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   keyboardState.keyState[e.keyCode] = true;
};


keyboardState.handleKeyUp = function(e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   keyboardState.keyState[e.keyCode] = false;
};

keyboardState.isKeyPressed = function(key) { return keyboardState.keyState[key]; };
```

...

```
<body class="unselectable" unselectable="on"
 onkeydown="keyboardState.handleKeyDown(event)"
 onkeyup="keyboardState.handleKeyUp(event)">
```

It seems that handleKeyDown is not even firing, if I'm debugging this right.  This must be pretty close to correct because it works fine in IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[prototype/javascript - firefox not firing keypress/keydown event unless focus is in textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630276/prototype-javascript-firefox-not-firing-keypress-keydown-event-unless-focus-is#answer-630739)

Try binding events on document instead of body. Also: try not to use 'onevent' attributes, but  create event listeners inside script block.

Comment: I'm using the attributes because I thought I saw some site suggesting it for cross-browser compatibility.  But now I can't find it.  Nevertheless I have implemented your suggestion by removing the onevent attributes and adding code like "document.onkeydown = keyboardState.handleKeyDown;" and things seem to be working in all browsers.  Thank you.